# Plot aggregate groupby Count data in SeaBorn Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

how to use groupby function in the y-axis? the below code doesn't display what i expect, due to y = df.groupby('column1')['column2'].count()

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

sns.stripplot(x="column1", y = df.groupby('column1')['column2'].count(), data=df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn just doesn't work that way. In seaborn, you specify the x and y columns as well as the data frame. Seaborn will do the aggregation itself.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.striplot('column1', 'column2', data=df)
```

For the count, maybe what you need is `countplot`

```
sns.countplot('column1', data=df)
```

The equivalent pandas code is:

```
df.groupby('column1').size().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: for grouping by, you can use parameter 'hue' within countplot

Answer (score 0):

this code will create a count plot with horizontal bar equivalent and descending sorted values

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,16))
grouped=df.groupby('Age').size(). \
sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='barh',ax=ax)
```